# Помогите разобраться с ответом от сервера codewars.com!

Tags: python-3.x, decode, encoder

Решаю вот такую ката с сайта

> https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ef9ca8b76be6d001d5e1c3e/train/python

> Она называется   Error correction #1 - Hamming Code   ===  Исправление
> ошибок # 1 - Код Хэмминга
> Код Хэмминга используется для исправления
> ошибок, так называемых переворотов битов, при передаче данных. Далее в
> описании следует подробное объяснение того, как это работает. В этом
> Кате мы реализуем код Хэмминга с длиной в 3 бита;

> Задача 1: функция кодирования
>
> Реализуйте функцию кодирования, выполнив следующие шаги:
>
> преобразовать каждую букву текста в ее значение ASCII;
> преобразовать

> значения ASCII в 8-битные двоичные файлы;
> утроить каждый бит;

> объединить результат
>
> input: "hey"
> --> 104, 101, 121                  // ASCII values
> --> 01101000, 01100101, 01111001   // binary
> --> 000111111000111000000000 000111111000000111000111 000111111111111000000111  // tripled
> --> "000111111000111000000000000111111000000111000111000111111111111000000111"
> // concatenated
>
> Задача 2: функция декодирования:
>
> Проверьте, не возникли ли ошибки, и исправьте их. Ошибками будут
> только перевороты битов, а не потеря битов:
>
> 111 -> 101: это может и случится 111 -> 11: этого не может быть
>
> Примечание: длина входной строки также всегда делится на 24, так что
> вы можете преобразовать ее в значение ASCII.
>
> Шаги:
>
> Разделите ввод на группы по три символа;
>
> Проверьте, не произошла ли ошибка: замените каждую группу символом,
> который встречается чаще всего, например 010 -> 0, 110 -> 1 и т. Д .;
>
> Возьмите каждую группу из 8 символов и преобразуйте это двоичное
> число;
>
> Преобразуйте двоичные значения в десятичные (ASCII);
>
> Преобразуйте значения ASCII в символы и объедините результат
>
> input:
> "100111111000111001000010000111111000000111001111000111110110111000010111"
> --> 100, 111, 111, 000, 111, 001, ...  // triples
> -->  0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   0,  ...  // corrected bits
> --> 01101000, 01100101, 01111001       // bytes
> --> 104, 101, 121                      // ASCII values
> --> "hey"

Вот мои две функции:

```
import re
from string import digits
from string import punctuation
from string import whitespace

def encode(string):
    lst = []
    for el in string:
        if el in punctuation or el in digits or el in whitespace: # add 1 bit
            lst.append(bin(ord(el)).replace('b', '0'))
        else:
            lst.append(bin(ord(el)).replace('b', ''))
    K = []    
    for st in lst:
        
        for chars in st:
            K.append(chars*3) # triple the beats
    bits = ''.join(K)
        
    return bits # get a concatenated string of triple bits


def decode(bits):
    binary = re.sub(r'(\d{3})', r'\1 ', bits)
    binary = binary.replace('000', '0').replace('111', '1').replace(' ', '')
    binary = re.sub(r'(\d{8})', r'\1 ', binary)
    binary = binary.split()
    lst = []
    for bi in binary:
        lst.append(int(bi, 2))
        
    string = ''
    for el in lst:
        string += chr(el)
    
    return string
```

Вот ответ от проверочного сервера:

```
Passed: 204 Failed: 104 Exit Code: 1

Test encode function ======================> я прохожу

Test decode function ==================> у меня не проходит
Should work with short word
'\x9aI\x93v%' should equal 'hey'
Completed in 0.37ms
Should work with long word
'U\x1a&U!\x14Ù[\x9cÚV\x92\x07FöÆD\x82me thb]\x12\x06\x92\x066\x16â\t\x91½ this kata' should equal 'The Sensei told me that i can do this kata'
```

У меня установлена ОС на базе ядра Linux Ubuntu 20.04.1
Программирую в Thonny(мне кажется тут самый лучший и понятный отладчик)
Самое главное в том что у меня в редакторе все получается и кодирование(получение битовой сконкатенированной строки) и декодирование(вставляю сконкатенированную битовую строку) === получаю строку ASCII

вот эта строка у меня в редакторе и кодируется и декодируется кодом Хемминга:

```
The Sensei told me that i can do this kata
```

а вот такую "байду" присылает сервер:

```
U\x1a&U!\x14Ù[\x9cÚV\x92\x07FöÆD\x82me thb]\x12\x06\x92\x066\x16â\t\x91½ this kata
```

Кто может, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА! объясните почему так происходит!

Comment: "Почему так происходит" Ваш код справляется с ошибками, которые вносите вы(в тестах, если они есть), но не справляется с теми, что вносит сервер.

Comment: И, собственно, где вы анализируете ошибки? `010 -> 0, 110 -> 1` вот эта часть задачи

Comment: У сервера есть базовые тесты и рандомные .В своём редакторе я прохожу все базовые тесты и некоторые рандомные.Но получаю --- сами видите что.

Comment: Ну, продолжайте тогда считать, что проблема на сервере codewars. Тут наши полномочия всё.

Comment: binary = re.sub(r'(\d{3})', r'\1 ', bits) --- из битовой строки делаем по 3 элемента
    binary = binary.replace('000', '0').replace('111', '1').replace(' ', '')  --- часто повторяемые если 000 меняем на 0, а 111 меняем на 1.Далее удаляем пробелы.
    binary = re.sub(r'(\d{8})', r'\1 ', binary) --- берём по 8 бит (для одного символа в ASCII)  и делаем список.Так вроде ошибок нет!

Comment: На что вы заменяете 010?

Comment: Перечитайте задание возле `this can and will happen`

Comment: 111 -> 101: это может и случится но у меня не случается, у меня было сперва что код пробела вместо 32 получался 64 --- было 7 бит ,Тогда для символов пришлось добавлять 1 бит применяя вот это if el in punctuation or el in digits or el in whitespace:
            lst.append(bin(ord(el)).replace('b', '0')) для знаков пунктуации и пробела перевода строки и прочих

Comment: Вы вообще поняли о чём эта задача? Это же код Хамминга, коррекция ошибок. Не ваших ошибок, а просто ошибок хранения/передачи данных.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, но хотелось бы получить балл за выполнения задания, как то в конце пути всё бросить___ ЖАЛКО  за проделанную работу

Comment: Ну так не бросайте, чините)

Comment: Ладно буду стараться! На сайте codewars писать надо по английски, а я не силен, а с переводом долго --- вот и приходится тут просить помощи

Answer (score 2):

У вас не было исправления ошибок в тройках битов, это когда выбирается тот бит, который встречается чаще.

Ваш код с регулярками получился симпотичным, единственная проблема, что вы схлопывали тройки одинаковых битов, а нужно было из них выбрать тот бит, что **чаще встречается**.

Пример выбора бита из троек (тут не имеет значение какой порядок битов):

- 110 или 111 -> 1 (сумма битов 2 или 3)
- 001 или 000 -> 0 (сумма битов 0 или 1)

Я исправил вашу функцию, попробуйте:

```
def decode(bits):
    binary = ''
    for tripled_bits in re.findall(r'\d{3}', bits):
        sums = sum(map(int, tripled_bits))
        binary += '1' if sums == 2 or sums == 3 else '0'

    text = ''
    for byte in re.findall(r'\d{8}', binary):
        text += chr(int(byte, 2))

    return text
```

---

**PS.**

Интересное задание :)

А у меня получилось [так](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/385a224b0702a0e21164b89eafc49c7c3734df58/codewars_Error_correction_1__Hamming_Code.py#L30):

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i: i + n]


def encode(text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(
        ''.join(b * 3 for b in f"{ord(c):08b}")  # Tripled bits
        for c in text
    )


def decode(bits: str) -> str:
    bit_items = []
    for tripled_bits in chunks(bits, 3):
        sums = sum(map(int, tripled_bits))

        # Example: 110 or 111 -> 1 and 000 -> 0 or 001 -> 0
        bit_items.append('1' if sums == 2 or sums == 3 else '0')

    binary = ''.join(bit_items)

    items = []
    for byte in chunks(binary, 8):
        items.append(chr(int(byte, 2)))

    return ''.join(items)
```

Comment: Это нечестно. Человек ушёл стараться, а вы ему решение)

Comment: @vp_arth, ну, вы ему объяснили в чем проблема ;) да и всегда можно учиться на чужом коде :)

Comment: Да конечно это целое решение --- и я не честно его сдал(только сейчас)--- спасибо конечно,НО ЕСЛИ МОЖНО ПОДСКАЖИТЕ В ЧЁМ ОШИБКА!!!

Comment: @андреймарченков, я обновил ответ, добавил исправленную функцию decode и написал в чем ошибка ;)

Comment: Смотрите, чтобы вам теперь аккаунты не объединили хД https://imgur.com/VPmcZGd.png

Comment: @vp_arth, это вряд ли :D

Comment: Вопрос закрыт всем спасибо!!!Да трудно понять смысл задания , да когда он ещё и на английском --- вот и вбираем смысл от переводчика Google

Comment: @андреймарченков, пожалуйста :) не забудьте проголосовать за понравившиеся ответы (стрелка вверх) и отметить ответ, что вас устроил галочкой

Answer (score 2):

Проблема не в ответе от сервера.
Просто вы не до конца поняли задачу.

С пониманием encode проблем у вас вроде нет (хотя код переусложнили)

А вот с decode проблемы.

> Проверьте, не возникли ли ошибки, и исправьте их.

Этот этап полностью пропущен.

Смысл задачи — коррекция ошибок. В каждом триплете входной последовательности один из трёх бит может быть неправильным. Перед декодированием вам нужно выяснить, каких бит в триплете больше и использовать его.

Проще и производительнее всего завести словарь замен с восемью вхождениями.

```
{'000': '0','001': '0','010': '0','011': '1','100': '0','101': '1','110': '1','111': '1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я решил её так:

```
hamm = {'000': '0','001': '0','010': '0','011': '1','100': '0','101': '1','110': '1','111': '1'}

def chunked_str(s, sz):
    return (s[i:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(s), sz))

def encode(string):
    return ''.join(3*bit for char in string for bit in format(ord(char), '08b'))

def decode(bits):
    repaired = ''.join(hamm[triplet] for triplet in chunked_str(bits, 3))
    return ''.join(chr(int(byte, 2)) for byte in chunked_str(repaired, 8))
```

Comment: А почему бы вам не перенести это решение в другой ответ? :)

Comment: Пусть будет) Это 2 разных ответа) Этот вообще никак не отвечает на поставленный вопрос) Плохой ответ, надо минус ставить)

Comment: Кст `''.join([...])` тут квадратные скобки лишние можно без них: `''.join(3*bit for char in string for bit in format(ord(char), 'b').zfill(8))`

Comment: Да тут много чего лишнего) format '08b' вместо zfill, например

Comment: У меня тоже, думаю лучше сделать как `f"{ord(char):08b}"`